# onchange event fires after clearing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have one fileupload control, after file upload clearing as below.

```
<input type="file" id="flupload1" **onchange="angular.element(this).scope().UploadPoster(event)"** file-upload /><br />
```

//Clear after file upload

```
document.getElementById('flupload1').value = "";
```

The problem is after clear again fileupload event triggering and one more time fileupload functionality is uploading.

but this behavior was behaving only in IE.

How to stop event trigger after clear value?

Answer (score 0):

This function may help you:

```
function clearFileInput(id) 
{ 
    let oldInput = document.getElementById(id); 
    let newInput = document.createElement("input"); 
    newInput.type = "file"; 
    newInput.id = oldInput.id; 
    newInput.name = oldInput.name; 
    newInput.className = oldInput.className; 
    newInput.style.cssText = oldInput.style.cssText; 
    // TODO: copy any other relevant attributes 
    oldInput.parentNode.replaceChild(oldInput.cloneNode(), oldInput);
}
clearFileInput("fileInput");
```

Comment: Setting readonly is not a good idea. upload is not allowing to upload file next time because of readonly.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain if you want to prevent user not to upload file this is best solution

Comment: I am not asking to prevent. My question is after clear value again fileupload triggering and  one more time uploading file.

Comment: okay then create one temporary variable and set it when first time file upload then check it when 2nd time file upload function is called just check that temp variable and check file is empty or not